# Program Design Questions

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

Good Day everyone,

I have a program design question (or questions) that I would love to get some feedback on.

Here is my situation:
I have

- Computer A running software A

  - Software A has different states (idle, processing, printing,...)
- Computer B running management software B
- These pieces of software are on 2 different machines.

What I really need is a way for the computer running software B to be able to tell what state software A is in.

I would like software A to send some kind of signal (message) to software B when it's state has changed.  I would also like software A to send it's state when software B requests it.

I have been thinking about using NService Bus or MSMQ between the two, but software B may be on a computer that is not on the current network (it may be in a 'Corporate Office' on their network).  Is there any other way to achieve what I want other than the two ways listed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Gateway](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859548-the-gateway-and-multi-site-distribution) feature in NSB.  This will allow HTTP communication between sites and will support all of your scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for that Adam. I will look into it as well as Web services.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I see it:

- Software A is a server
- Software B (Management software is a client)

Good design shall always ensure that the server never sends something on its own. I would develop a simple HTTP based protocol (REST API or **Web Services** if you want to do it perfectly and in a W3C standard) to query Software A remotely. This way you can even develop client software that runs in a browser. The clients can connect through firewalls and proxies, so you shall just make sure requests for Software A are relayed appropriately inside your company.

I cannot read much about other constraints but if you only have to monitor a status, then this is definitively enough. To avoid polling you can use [WS-Eventing](http://www.w3.org/Submission/WS-Eventing/).

Comment: Thank you for that information, but you have the Software locations backwards.  Software A is the Client and Software B is on the server. I was thinking along the same lines for computers that aren't on the same network, but wouldn't that lead to possible hijacking of data? (In case I want to change what goes from A to B)